# In-App Purchase doesn't send SKPaymentCancelled when cancelling from login UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I am writing an application that uses in-app purchase. It is currently able to retrieve product id's and I can successfully test the in-app purchase through to completion.

The problem I am having is the error handling. What I wanted to do was display a UIAlertView when the transaction fails as long as it is not failing by SKPaymentCancelled, in which case it will just default back to a normal condition before the purchase. The problem is if I click on my Buy It Now button and then click OK to make the purchase, the store asks for my username and password. If I click cancel at that point, it is not sending SKPaymentCancelled. Instead it will display my UIAlertView which means it does not treat this as a cancelled payment. I am wondering how I should handle this condition as I don't want an alert to pop up if the user cancels, even at the login screen.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you accidentally trying to use a LIVE iTunes account rather than a test account? I've just tried that in my current project while using the sandbox, and you get SKErrorUnknown when you cancel at that point if you are using a LIVE account by mistake.

Equally it could be the sandbox playing up - I've lost track of how much downtime in a project is caused by sandbox 'temporary' issues.

Comment: I am not using a LIVE iTunes account. It is definitely a test user and as I said in my post I can make the purchase through the test user. I did some more testing and found out it is setting a SKErrorUnknown type when the login is cancelled. For now, I have just set my code to not flash up a UIAlertView if it receives a SKErrorUnknown. If you have any other suggestions, I'd be happy to hear. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I'm seeing all sorts of odd errors this morning with the sandbox, it was working for about 5 minutes and now I'm getting nothing but Error -1003. I'd file a bug over at bugreport.apple.com as my guess is they have broken something and may or may not already know depending on whether it is also affecting any live services. They're quite good at responding usually.

Comment: Try creating a new test user - that has just cleared it for me. I wonder if the old test user saw the live store by mistake - it doesn't like that.

Comment: I have tried that. Same error when exiting from the login screen. I have filed a bug with Apple.